"Error: The system cannot find the path specified during Qt build with jom"
/OUT:release\RPA_Config.exe @C:\Users\pawan\AppData\Local\Temp\RPA_Config.exe.26844.11344.jom
The system cannot find the path specified.
jom: C:\Users\pawan\OneDrive\Desktop\RPA_Config_Clone\build-Desktop_Qt_6_7_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Release\Makefile.Release [release\RPA_Config.exe] Error 1
jom: C:\Users\pawan\OneDrive\Desktop\RPA_Config_Clone\build-Desktop_Qt_6_7_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Release\Makefile [release] Error 2
17:31:52: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project RPA_Config (kit: Desktop Qt 6.7.1 MSVC2019 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
when building my project on msvc2019 compiler in qt at the time compilation above error is occurs how can solve these error?
For solving these error i have try below steps:

I have shift Mingw compiler to MSVC2019_64 for that install visual Studio 2022 and download MSVC 2019 compiler
In qt build my project using these compiler but it gives above error for that i have change environment variables paths and also configure quazip, sqlcipher, SDL added these DLL in my project also added its path in .pro file

Build Environment Path Img
Pro file path img
